# C# - Convert decimal to int32

Tags: c#, .net, math, rounding

I have the following code:

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(4.5m);
int b = Convert.ToInt32(5.5m);

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

And here's the output:

```
4
6
```

Why does `Convert.ToInt32` rounds decimal values to the nearest even number?

Comment: but, why expect something different ?

Comment: Ok I would have expect a=5 and b= 6

Comment: Define "nearest". 4 and 6 are an equal distance to 5.5

Comment: @tigran because it's irregular, 1st goes down, 2nd goes up. not all know about bankers rounding ;)

Comment: @Ramhound, I expect 4-5 or 5-6. Not the nearest even number.

Comment: see my answer below for a poor definition of bankers rounding.  or research it yourself for a better answer.  Dirk explains how to choose what form of rounding you wish.  the Answer by ie nailed it as well.  better explanation then mine, though I sense a cut and paste.  guess thats acceptable, but a link to that info would have been better IMO.

Comment: What is the result you want for `4.6`?

Comment: @Oded:  5.5 is definitely closer to 6 than it is to 4!

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - True... you know what I meant... It is equidistant to 5 and 6.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Convert is using rounding to nearest, or banker's rounding:

> The behavior of this method follows IEEE Standard 754, section 4. This
>   kind of rounding is sometimes called rounding to nearest, or banker's
>   rounding. It minimizes rounding errors that result from consistently
>   rounding a midpoint value in a single direction.
>
> To control the type of rounding used by the Round method, call the
>   Math.Round(Double, MidpointRounding) overload.

Answer (score 13):

```
int a = (int)Math.Floor(4.5m);
int b = (int)Math.Floor(5.5m);
```

[**MSDN**:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7ycc7xh)

Or:

```
int a = decimal.ToInt32(4.5m);
int b = decimal.ToInt32(4.5m)
```

---

You can also just use the explicit int cast operator:

```
int a = (int) 4.5m;
int b = (int) 5.5m;
```

But read this note from [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf02hx8s.aspx):

> This operator supports the explicit conversion of a Decimal to a Int32. The syntax for such explicit conversions is language-dependent, and individual language compilers can provide different implementations and return different results. The example illustrates the different return values when you explicitly convert a Decimal value to an Int32 value by using C# and Visual Basic. To perform a conversion that is independent of language, you can call the ToInt32 or the Convert.ToInt32(Decimal) method.

---

```
Math.Floor Method (Decimal)
```

> Returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified decimal number.

Note that decimal is bigger than `int` so if the value is bigger than `int.MaxValue` you get an `OverflowException`

Comment: +1 Damn! Beat me to it :) while I was waiting for a confirmation from the OP

Comment: Math.Floor always rounds down is that what the OP wants.  what if it was (4.9m)  you would get 4

Comment: Just (int) will also do the job.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal. That depends on negative numbers.

Comment: Why have so many people voted this answer up?  This does NOT do what the author wants.

Comment: @K'Leg. This is what he was asking.

Comment: @gdoron if that is what he was asking then for sure this is the answer, I am just not certain he wanted Floor.

Comment: @K'Leg. I asked him it one min ago, let's see what his answer will be.

Comment: @gdoron  Its ok either way, if this was what he wanted he will choose this as answer.

Comment: @K'Leg. a decent comment, unlike Ramhound comments... :)

Comment: @gdoron I think he jumps to conclusions to fast, he marked my answer down below accusing me of repeating others answer, where as my answer was posted around the same time as yours, which was first, and it doesn't repeat yours,  But thats ok, we are here to help other people and get help ourselves, I learned as much from this question as I taught.

Answer (score 5):

Math.Round() allows you to choose

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(4.5m, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven));  //4
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(5.5m, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven));  //6

Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(4.5m, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));  //5
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(5.5m, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));  //6
```

(And, as you would guess, default is `ToEven`)

Answer (score 4):

It does that because [that's how it's defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93kx4xke) (see below for reason):

> Returns: value, rounded to the nearest 32-bit signed integer. If value is
>   halfway between two whole numbers, the even number is returned; that
>   is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted to 6.

you'd have to use something like `Math.Floor` if you want different results.

The documentation for [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk), which does the same thing, states the reason:

> The behavior of this method follows IEEE Standard 754, section 4. This
>   kind of rounding is sometimes called rounding to nearest, or banker's
>   rounding. It minimizes rounding errors that result from consistently
>   rounding a midpoint value in a single direction.
>
> To control the type of rounding used by the Round(Decimal) method,
>   call the Math.Round(Decimal, MidpointRounding) overload.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know the reason :) MSDN's explanation doesn't make any sense.

Comment: see my answer below I think it sort of explains it.  and Dirk shows how to choose which way you wish to round

Comment: @šljaker - The fact you are asking and are expecting entirely incorrect results clearly shows you DO NOT know the reason.  Besides you asked `"why is this happening?"`

Comment: @šljaker I extended my answer to provide an explanation. `Convert.ToInt32(decimal)` does the same type of rounding like `Math.Round` by default.

Answer (score 0):

I read something yesterday that when rounding occurs it rounds to the nearest even number, its called bankers rounding.  You have to tell it how you want to round

EDIT:  you asked for an explanation of why it rounds to the nearest even number.

say you have 10 numbers (this is an extreme case

1.5,
2.5,
3.5,
4.5,
5.5,
6.5,
7.5,
8.5,
9.5,
10.5

the sum = 60

if you round them all off first

the sum = 65  because they would all round up

if you bankers round them

the sum = 60

Comment: This just repeats a previous answer and doesn't explain the reason this rounding method is even used.

Comment: @Ramhound Check the times the answers were added...  they repeated me not the otherway around, and I agree I didn't explain why except to state that it adds accuracy, which is why in other comments I have made I told people to read their answers

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93kx4xke

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Int32 value, rounded to the nearest 32-bit signed
>   integer. If value is halfway between two whole numbers, the even
>   number is returned; that is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is
>   converted to 6.

Comment: All you did was repeat what `Botz3000` already said.  I don't understand the point of this answer.

Comment: If you look at the timestamp you can see that we posted at the same time.